# Process Dump analysis of 32 bit process for High CPU usage

Tags: windows, profiling, visual-studio-debugging

I have a 32 bit CPP windows service application, some times randomly it's CPU usage goes high (70%). I have taken process dump's of the exe from 32 bit taskmanager (32 bit dump) and 64 bit task manager (64 bit dump). Can anyone please guide me how to analyse these dumps to figure out which part of my code is causing this high CPU usage.

Comment: you should be able to open it in visual studio or windbg

Comment: Open the dump in WinDbg and use `!runaway`. This gives you a break down of how much time each thread in the process has spent. See help file for details.

Comment: I am using VS to debug the dump, i see multiple threads running while debugging the dump. Is there anyway we can know which thread is taking high CPU?? @BrianRasmussen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Process Dump analysis of 32 bit process for High CPU usage

I suggest you could debug these dump files in visual studio so that you can find that where goes wrong.

**Suggestion**

**1)** [install Windows Driver Kit in VS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/download-the-wdk)

**2)** open VS and slect File-->Open-->File-->choose the dump file.

**3)** config the path of dll and pdb files(`xxx\project name\bin\Debug`) into Symbols Window and also check Microsoft Symbol Server under Symbols Window.

**4)** then you can click **Debug with Managed Only** to debug.

You can refer to [Use Visual Studio to debug the dump files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/using-dump-files?view=vs-2019) for more detailed steps.

**In addition**, you can also try to [use Windbg to analysis dump files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/crash-dump-files) and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dxtecharts/crash-dump-analysis?redirectedfrom=MSDN#debugging-a-minidump-with-windbg).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am using VS to debug the dump, i see multiple threads running while debugging the dump. Is there anyway we can know which thread is taking high CPU?? @Perry Qian-MSFT